# Simple Regex with Date

Tags: regex, dreamweaver

I'm using Dreamweaver to replace about 1,000 instances of page titles that have a similar format:

5 5 2016 Nice tasty halibut

5 19 2016 A good king salmon and halibut day
...

I'd like the date to be formatted like:

5-5-2016 Nice tasty halibut

5-19-2016 A good king salmon and halibut day

I tried several ways of using Regular Expressions to fix this, but couldn't get the replaced value with the desired format.  Can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggest using `([0-9]{1,2})\s+([0-9]{1,2})\s+([0-9]{4})`.

This is a stricter regexpr. Essentially you are capturing 3 groups of numbers where

1. Group 1 must be digits and there can only be 1 or 2.
2. Group 2, same 1 or 2 digits.
3. Group 3, exactly 4 digits for the year.
4. Group 4, rest of the string.

And `\s+` means 1 or more white spaces.

Then `$1-$2-$3 $4` to match back all 4 groups together.

**See:** 
https://regex101.com/r/wO3wD6/1

Answer (score 1):

Search for `([0-9]+) ([0-9]+) (.*)` and replace it with `$1-$2-$3`.